# startActivityForResult from a ListFragment doesn't seem to call onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb

I did try the "fixed" jar here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15394

and also reinstalled the SDK completely and neither approach still fixed the issue I have here.  So is `startActivityForResult` just a no go from `ListFragment`?

Original post:

I have this `ClientListView` which is a `ListFragment`, that when the button on the action bar is clicked it takes what is selected in the `ListFragment` view and starts a new activity to edit the selected client (or if the other option is clicked a new client all together).

This all launches fine.  The `ClientListView`  fragment and the `ClientDetailsFragment` are replaced by my `EditClientActivity` FragmentActivity (which calls the `ClientEdit` fragment).  This takes up the whole screen and creates a save/cancel button in the action bar.

The problem is that when the save is clicked, I cannot update my `ListFragment` with the newly created client or edited client.  For completeness this is my calling order:

`MainActivity FragmentActivity` sets up the `ClientListView ListFragment` and the `ClientDetailsActivity FragmentActivity` (which has the `ClientDetails` fragment).  Then the `ClientListView ListFragment` upon its new or edit client option being selected can startActivityForResult on the `EditClientActivity` (Which has the `ClientEdit` fragment in it).

The `ClientEdit` Fragment sets up the options menu for save cancel, once the save in the `ClientEdit` fragment is selected several things happen:

new client or edited client is saved to the database.
`mEditListener.onEditComplete()` is called.  As the calling `FragmentActivity` `EditClientActivity` implements an `onEditCompleteListener` that i use `onAttach` in the `ClientEdit` fragment.

So then my `EditClientActivity` has the `onEditComplete(long id)` method:

```
public void onEditComplete(long id) {
    Intent in  = new Intent();
    this.setResult(1, in); //just something to let the ClientListView that the client i saved refresh the list.
    Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Client Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish(); //go back to our listview and client details view
}
```

In my `ClientListView` (of type 'ListFragment') I have this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
     //which columns to put as the cursor
 String[] columns = new String[] { "firstname", "lastname" };
 //how to post those columns into the layout.  check client_row.xml for these ids
 int[] to = new int[] { R.id.client_first_name_list_label,  R.id.client_last_name_list_label};

    myCursor = getClientsCursor(); //this is NOT closing the database connection if it does it gets an error

    theClients = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getListView().getContext(),
    R.layout.client_row, myCursor, columns, to);
    setListAdapter(theClients);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_client:
                // TODO: add recipe
                showClientEdit(-1);
                return true;
        case R.id.client_delete:
                // TODO: delete recipe
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Delete Client selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
        case R.id.client_edit:
               if(mCurrentSelectedItemIndex!=-1)
                   showClientEdit(mCurrentSelectedItemIndex);
               else
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select client to edit!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
                // TODO: Handle app icon click
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Home icon selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
        default:                
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


void showClientEdit(long someId)
{
  ..do stuff to get the right client to pass to the intent
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditClientActivity.class);
  // Send the recipe index to the new activity
  intent.putExtra(EditClientActivity.SELECTED_CLIENT, clientId);
  startActivityForResult(intent, Activity.RESULT_OK);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
   //never gets here :(
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(this.getListView().getContext(), "Result code: " +resultCode , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(resultCode ==1)
        {
            myCursor = getClientsCursor(); //not sure if i need this for the next line or not, want my list to update with newly
            //added client or edited client names etc...
            theClients.notifyDataSetChanged();                
            Toast.makeText(this.getListView().getContext(), "Data set notified!!!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }                       
}
```

Is the issue is that my `startActivityForRestult` calls the `EditClientActivity` from a ListFragment? As far as I can tell never calls the `onActivityResult`.  I provided all this information to try to figure out and get a handle on how Fragment/FragmentActivities and the like are all supposed to interact with each other.  I am doing it this way from things I learned poking around tutorials, the developer guide etc.  I am pretty happy with my progress but at a wall now...and probably realizing the way I am doing things is just not the right way...I would love to be enlightened.  This is the hardest part of android to me is managing how all these activities and views interact with each other....

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the compatibility library for Fragments?

There is an issue with the Compatibility package, onActivityResult within fragments is broken. Take a look here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15394 . There you can also download a jar file with the fixed version.

Comment: U know what if that's the jars that r in extra folder then yep. Guessing I grab the fixed one and let it rip..if so then my on activity should work I hope?  Is the way my update of my adapter to hupdate the list correct?  I.e. the code in onActivityResult?

Comment: onActivityResult should work with that fixed jar, give it a try, its only a matter of switching the jar

Comment: Got that fixed jar, rebuilt, put in breakpoint the onActivityResult in my still isn't firing in my public class ClientListView extends ListFragment.  I am not sure what to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this question is old, but I wanted to provide a solution for those that are hitting this question like I did when they were searching for why your `onActivityResult` is not running when the `Intent` is called from inside a fragment (`ListFragment` or regular `Fragment` will have the same result).

You must call your `startActivityForResult` from your main Activity. So make sure to call `getActivity()` when you call it from inside a fragment like this:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent,ACTIVITY_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Freaking figured this out.  It was the way I was using the Result/request code:

`startActivityForResult(intent, Activity.RESULT_OK);`

was not the way to start it, added another number in there instead of `Activity.RESULT_OK` and it worked, I must of gotten confused.

Comment: You should use that constant there anyway, it's asking for a request code to identify your request, and your trying to pass a result code that you  use when the resultant activity is finished.